# For loop runs correctly but only on one layer - PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-3, pyqgis-3

I am trying to automate the creation of null raster files from vectors.
I have this code:

```
import glob
files = glob.glob("C:/Users/joel/folder/*.shp")
for file in files:
    iface.addVectorLayer(file, "", "ogr")
    processing.runAndLoadResults("saga:rasterize", {'INPUT':file,'FIELD':'max','OUTPUT':'2','MULTIPLE':'4','LINE_TYPE':'0','POLY_TYPE':'1','GRID_TYPE':'3','TARGET_USER_XMIN TARGET_USER_XMAX TARGET_USER_YMIN TARGET_USER_YMAX':None,'TARGET_USER_SIZE':'1','TARGET_USER_FITS':'1','GRID':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT'})

rasters = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('Rasterized')

for raster in rasters:
    processing.runAndLoadResults("grass7:r.null", {'map':raster,'setnull':'-99999','null':'0','-f':False,'-i':False,'-n':False,'-c':False,'-r':False,'output':'TEMPORARY_OUTPUT','GRASS_REGION_PARAMETER':None,'GRASS_REGION_CELLSIZE_PARAMETER':'0','GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_OPT':'','GRASS_RASTER_FORMAT_META':''})
```

I am testing the code on a folder with four shapefiles in. The rasterization process works fine, but when I try to run `r.null` the process runs four times on the same raster layer when I would like it to run once on each layer.

Comment: what is in `rasters`?

Comment: the four rasterized shape files produced by `rasterize`

Comment: Do you have any `Rasterized` layer before running the script?

Comment: can you print it out to be sure?

Comment: No, the problem still occurs in a completely new project.

Comment: If I print `rasters` I get:
`[<QgsMapLayer: 'Rasterized' (gdal)>, <QgsMapLayer: 'Rasterized' (gdal)>, <QgsMapLayer: 'Rasterized' (gdal)>, <QgsMapLayer: 'Rasterized' (gdal)>]`

Unless `rasters` contains the same raster layer four times I don't think that is the problem

Comment: What is the version of QGIS?

Comment: QGIS version is 3.14.15

Comment: I didn't change anything and the issue seems to be solved now.... not too sure how that happened